# What is considered a header and footer in a text formatted for printing?

Tags: text-processing, nl

From `nl` manual:

```
...

-f, --footer-numbering=STYLE
          use STYLE for numbering footer lines

-h, --header-numbering=STYLE
       use STYLE for numbering header lines

...
```

Can you provide an example of usage of the `-f` and `-h` option? What is considered as being a footer or header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're reading the manpage of GNU `nl`. The full documentation in `info nl` (or [online](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/nl-invocation.html#nl-invocation)) describes it more completelye:

> `nl` decomposes its input into (logical) page sections; by default, the
>   line number is reset to 1 at each logical page section. `nl` treats all
>   of the input files as a single document; it does not reset line
>   numbers or logical pages between files.
>
> A logical page consists of three sections: header, body, and footer.
>   Any of the sections can be empty. Each can be numbered in a different
>   style from the others.
>
> The beginnings of the sections of logical pages are indicated in the
>   input file by a line containing exactly one of these delimiter
>   strings:
>
> `\:\:\:`
>   start of header;
>
> `\:\:`
>   start of body;
>
> `\:`
>   start of footer.
>
> The two characters from which these strings are made can be changed
>   from `\` and `:` via options (see below), but the pattern and length
>   of each string cannot be changed.
>
> A section delimiter is replaced by an empty line on output. Any text
>   that comes before the first section delimiter string in the input file
>   is considered to be part of a body section, so `nl` treats a file that
>   contains no section delimiters as a single body section.

Or, similarly from [the POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nl.html):

> The `nl` utility views the text it reads in terms of logical pages.
>   Line numbering shall be reset at the start of each logical page. A
>   logical page consists of a header, a body, and a footer section. Empty
>   sections are valid. Different line numbering options are independently
>   available for header, body, and footer (for example, no numbering of
>   header and footer lines while numbering blank lines only in the body).
>
> The starts of logical page sections shall be signaled by input lines
>   containing nothing but the following delimiter characters:
>
> ```
> Line                           Start of
> \:\:\:                         Header
> \:\:                           Body
> \:                             Footer
> ```

An example:

```
% printf "\\:\\:\n%s\n\\:\nfooter\n" {a..c} | nl

     1  a

       footer

     1  b

       footer

     1  c

       footer
% printf "\\:\\:\n%s\n\\:\nfooter\n" {a..c} | nl -f a

     1  a

     1  footer

     1  b

     1  footer

     1  c

     1  footer
```